# Karate: How to wait for a spinner to disappear?

Tags: ui-automation, karate

I want to wait for a spinner (text()='XYZ..') to disappear.

I have tried:
waitUntil(condition) and waitFor('{}' + locator) but they don't work. Any other solution?